# awk find for strings and output in a table manner

Tags: awk

I have many file that i want to search specific strings in each file.
I used awk to find for strings and will output it in a table manner,
I have tried this code.

```
awk '$2 ~ /Sting1/ {print $1, $3} $1 ~ /String2/  {print $2}' *.log
```

which outputs:

```
String1a String1-2a

String2a

String1b String1-2b

String2b
```

Desired output:

```
String1a String1-2a String2a

String1b String1-2b String2b
```

Please help me improved my code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the input file format too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a newline after printing `$1` and `$3`, you can use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
awk '$2 ~ /String1/ {printf "%s %s ", $1, $3} $1 ~ /String2/  {print $2}' *.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `ORS` variable to set the output record separator as

```
$ awk  '$2 ~ /String1/{ORS=""; print $1, $3} $1 ~ /String2/{ORS="\n"; print $2}' input
ng1a String1-2aString2a
String1b String1-2bString2b
```

Comment: This works too but I need the result from string1 and string2 to have space in between. Thanks a lot for this...  I just change ORS=""; to ORS=" "; and it I got the result I want. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then this awk one liner will do as you wish!!

```
awk -v ORS="\n\n" 'NR%4{printf "%s ",$0;next}1' *.log
```

Output:

```
$ awk -v ORS="\n\n" 'NR%4{printf "%s ",$0;next}1' file
String1a String1-2a  String2a

String1b String1-2b  String2b
```

If there are no spaces between the lines, you must change NR%4 for NR%2!.

Comment: `printf "%s ",$0` would be more natural, concise and efficient than `printf "%s",$0" "`. You also don't need the trailing semi-colon after `next`.